# Is there an Excel formula to provide nth occurrence within a group

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find a formula to give me the values in 'value' column. I have 2 groupings of items in column A and B. These are overlapping. Given the Product Group in column 1, I want the rank of the Vendor.

I've tried various array formula with if's but am having difficulty figuring it out.

EDIT1:

updating column names so its a bit clearer. my final result wants to be the Product Group_vendor rank column which concatenates the Vendor [B] and the value [D].

See below for example:

|  | A: Product Group | B: Vendor | C: Product | D: value | E: Product Group_vendor rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 01 | bikes | 1 | a-1 |
| 2 | a | 01 | sandals | 1 | a-1 |
| 3 | a | 01 | jeans | 1 | a-1 |
| 4 | a | 02 | barbies | 2 | a-2 |
| 4 | b | 01 | rats | 1 | b-1 |
| 5 | b | 02 | pants | 2 | b-2 |
| 6 | b | 03 | legos | 3 | b-3 |
| 7 | c | 04 | widgets | 1 | c-1 |
| 8 | c | 05 | patches | 2 | c-2 |
| 9 | c | 05 | jewels | 2 | c-2 |
| 10 | c | 06 | bottles | 3 | c-3 |

Comment: You should post an example of your expected output

Comment: Take a look at the D:values column. It is my expected output given  inputs of columns A, B, C

Comment: What is `n` value for this data? thanks

Comment: @JohnnieL, not sure what you mean.

my actual dataset has 300 lines. it is a summarized report which lists the product group and the vendor. both of those values can change in the report input. 

i'm hoping to write formula with input from columns A, B, C and results in D, E

Comment: Please include your own attempt *and* let us know what version of Excel you are using

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a combo of index match with an array.  You'll need to enter the equation as an array, so hit ctrl + shift + enter instead of just enter after building it.  The {} tells excel it's an array function

First you need a cell with your target group and value for n. For example I'll use G1 for target group and H1 as n.

{=INDEX(D1:D10,SMALL(IF(B1:B10=G1,ROW(B1:B10)-ROW(INDEX(B1:B10,1,1))+1),H1))}

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this.

Comment: I've tried to work this into my table but have not had success. Can you take a look at the updated requirements in my post?

Comment: It seems like your requirements have changed quite a bit.  Am I understanding correctly that all but the product group vendor rank already exists?

Answer (score 0):

This formula will work **only if your data is sorted** like the one you've posted (it looks like everything is sorted first by column A and then by column B):

[image]

```
=IF(AND(A2=A1;B2=B1);D1;IF(A2=A1;D1+1;1))
```

In column E, formula is just `=A2&"-"&D2`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, pasted into `D2`

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A12,A2:A12,B2:B12,">="&B2:B12)
```